# why is my UIButton changing size and position after assigning an image? How can I keep it the same?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, storyboard

my UIButton size and position changes after I assign an image to it. I am not sure why. Does anyone know?

I tried repositioning the button to its original position but it doesnt work.

```
CGRect buttonFrame = _subscribeButton.frame;
CGAffineTransform transform = _subscribeButton.transform;

[_subscribeButton setTitle:@"Subscribe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_subscribeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_subscribeButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
[_subscribeButton setTransform:transform];
```

Comment: r u using autolayout?

Comment: I have autolayout turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be setting backgroundImage not image. this was the problem the whole time. aspect fill only effects the background image as this is scaled by the frame.

answer: [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"]];

Answer (score 0):

```
change this

CGAffineTransform transform = _subscribeButton.transform;

to

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

**Update:**

```
CGRect buttonFrame = _subscribeButton.frame;

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

[_subscribeButton setTitle:@"Subscribe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_subscribeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_subscribeButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

_subscribeButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

_subscribeButton.autoresizesSubviews = NO;



[_subscribeButton setFrame:buttonFrame];

[_subscribeButton setTransform:transform];
```

Comment: setting the autoresizing mask to none has not made any effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 CGRect buttonFrame = _subscribeButton.frame;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    [_subscribeButton setTitle:@"Subscribe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_subscribeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_subscribeButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
    [_subscribeButton setTransform:transform];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html refer this